# Can behat check that steps are defined before trying to run anything?

Tags: php, testing, bdd, behat

I've got a behat scenario that takes a long time to run.  If I've written a step incorrectly, I have to wait for the test to hit that step before I find out my mistake when it tells me I've got an undefined step.

Is there a way to get behat to check that all the steps it's going to try and run are defined, before it tries to run anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **dry run** option to prevent step execution:

```sh
bin/behat --dry-run
```

In the long run, you should rather fix your tests and make them quicker. For example, only execute end-to-end tests for small number of smoke tests (critical paths), and run most of your acceptance tests against your business objects.