# Find what step N is in Behat

Tags: php, bdd, behat

I'm running a small suite of Behat tests, and getting an error in my Feature Context.

I can see that the error is triggered by trying to deserialise invalid json in my FeatureContext (`json_decode()`). However, I can't see the string it was trying to deserialise.

```
...................................................................... 70
...................................................................... 140
...................................................................... 210
...................................................................... 280
...................................................................... 350
...................................................................... 420
...................................................................... 490
...................................................................... 560
...................................................................... 630
...................................................................... 700
......................PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access property started with '\0' in tests/Behat/FeatureContext.php on line 512
```

I can see this is step #722. Is there an easy way to get the Feature, and line number from that?

I realise I *can* run this with pretty format on, and that will work in this case, but some of my other suites take over 2 hours to run. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: You can log all strings before `json_decode()`, when you get fatal, the last string in the log is one that breaks.

Comment: It is an option, but as with turning on pretty format, this requires re-running tests. Again, in this case it's fine, but I have other tests that take over 2 hours to run, and logging every response in those tests would be infeasible.

Comment: You can grep output for `PHP Fatal error` and see lines above to filter the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be no way to know which **Step** failed if you haven't prepared your test suite for that. Steps are also "multiplied" but the **Scenario outline** cases, which makes it even harder to write any hacky Features parsing script to just count up all the steps as they might've been parsed by Behat.

But for the future you can use "Before step" and "Before scenario" hooks to log step contents and scenario names. This way you should have all their names logged as a list.

Comment: This is *probably* the correct answer, though I also don't think multiplying steps by number of outline examples adds much work when parsing the feature because the number of steps in the scenario doesn't actually change based on example content. I'll hold out for other thoughts before closing this off. I **do** think logging before and after each step is probably a good idea anyway and will add this to my FeatureContext.

Comment: You could probably make some use of --dry-run option to, maybe, grep the line by number or something. This moght actually save you some time debugging in future ;-) see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/29032687/1808052